# Photoshop Selection and canvas bugs

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing, canvas

Since I upgraded to the new Photoshop CC 2015 I've been having some problems with the selection tool. When making a selection I often get double lines, lines stay after deselection and one selection can be in multiple parts. The selections works as it should, but it looks very different and makes it annoying. Does anyone know the problem and know how to fix this?

I also have some gray space issue with some canvasses, it looks like there stays a gray part over my canvas. Its not a layer and it stays in my screen. Sometimes it helps to close the file and reopen it. Sometimes it just stays. It looks like its there fixed and its not always the same in the same files. Like the file you can see here, is a new, empty file.

Can anyone please help me? Working with the newest Photoshop version in this way is horrible.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was [apparently fixed](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/select-tool-creating-excess-visual-selections-and-copying-itself-when-dragged) with the 2015.0.1 update, make sure you've updated to that version.

It seems to be related to GPU Performance Settings, so if upgrading doesn't fix it (or you're already on that version) you could try the following:

- Upgrading your graphics card drivers.
- Enabling/disabling `Use Graphics Processor` in `Preferences > Perfornance`
- If enabling `Use Graphics Processor` try switching the `Drawing Mode` to `Basic` in the `Advanced Graphics Porcessor Settings`

Comment: I tried enabling my graphics processor, which disabled before already because of this problems. It looks like its working. Gonna check now if Adobe will let me update to .0.1. In some way I always have fights with Adobe Cloud, it worked better without a licence.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too. Just resize the zoom (pinch in or out or cntrl + or -) and it will be cleared. Its the best solution for the bug. Lets hope the bug is solved in the new CC versions.